# Add watermark to each frame while creating video from images using ffmpeg

Tags: c++, linux, ffmpeg

I am basically creating video from opengl animation uisng `glreadpixels` and unix pipeline : 
`FILE *ffmpeg = popen("/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.5.4/bin/ffmpeg"
                     " -framerate 30"
                     " -vcodec rawvideo"
                     " -f rawvideo"
                     " -pix_fmt rgb32"
                     " -s 1080x720"
                     " -i pipe:0 -vf vflip -vcodec h264"
                     " -r 60"
                     " /Users/xamarin/Desktop/out.mp4", "w");`
Is it possible to add watermark in each frame as i am creating frames for video. I know how to add watermark in existing video but i want to add watermark as i am creating video so that in on step i get video that has watermark in it. Suggest me some parameters for `ffmpeg` that can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

```
ffmpeg \
-framerate 30 -f rawvideo -pixel_format rgb32 -video_size 1080x720 -i pipe:0 \
-i overlay.png \
-i audio.foo \
-filter_complex "[0:v]vflip[main];[main][1:v]overlay=format=rgb,format=yuv420p" \
-c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- The [rawvideo demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo) lists `-pixel_format` instead of `-pix_fmt` and `-video_size` instead of `-s`.
- You probably don't need `-c:v rawvideo` when you include `-f rawvideo`.
- I removed `-r 60` because it seems unnecessary to duplicate the frames.
- You may see a visual improvement when adding `format=rgb` to the overlay filter for RGB inputs. The format filter is then used to make H.264 output with YUV 4:2:0 chroma subsampling which is needed for non-FFmpeg based players.
- `-movflags +faststart` is helpful if your viewers will watch via progressive download.

Comment: can i add audio during this process as well. In other words, create video using rawvideo (frames from opengl animation), watermark image and audio file in one step? @LordNeckbeard

Comment: thank you so much!!!! made my life easier. ffmpeg is very interesting. Can you suggest me any tutorials/websites to learn it. Their official documentation is little bit too formal and hard to understand. And it seems it is not updated too. I used "pixel_fmt" because it is listed in documentation located at their website. Secondly, there is very little info regarding filter_complex in doc as well.

Comment: @asad The [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/#CommunityContributedDocumentation) has some useful articles.